# Is there a Logger.setLevel like method in Android class Log?

Tags: android, logging

Is there a `Logger.setLevel`-like method in the Android class `Log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there are no built in methods for this in [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class.[As per I know].

But you can build your own like:

```
public void setLevel(int level) {
    switch (level) {
        case OFF:
               this.logger.setLevel(Level.OFF); 
               break;
        case ALL:
               this.logger.setLevel(Level.ALL); 
               break;
        case INFO:
               this.logger.setLevel(Level.INFO); 
               break;
        case WARN:
               this.logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING); 
               break;
        case ERROR:
               this.logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE); 
               break;
        default:
               break;
        }
}
```

Also You can change the default level by setting a system property: `setprop log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG> <LEVEL>` where level is either VERBOSE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, ASSERT, or SUPPRESS.

You can also create a local.prop file that with the following in it: `log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG>=<LEVEL>` and place that in /data/local.prop. `setprop log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG> <LEVEL>`

Answer (score 1):

No. `android.util.Log` relies on the log viewer to filter out the desired priority:`logcat` lets you pick which severity you want (ASSERT/DEBUG/ERROR/INFO/VERBOSE/WARN).

Comment: Example reading warning level log messages: `adb logcat *:W`   


Good article with details, [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html)